# C# how to define global constants like api keys and prevent from being uploaded to Github

Tags: c#, git, github, constants

I'm working on a Visual Studio C# project (.net 4.7.2) where I need to store some private API keys as constants.  The project gets uploaded to a public github repo, but I don't want the API keys to be shared.
What is the best practice for achieving this?

It seems if I create a Constants class file with a static class containing the constant values, then omit file via .gitignore, the project won't build for other users who download it because the file will be missing.   If I upload the skeleton of the file first, then omit it via .gitignore, it won't be updated if I change or add new constants later.

I'm looking for best practices to achieve this.

Comment: Set up [user secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows) and use the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 4):

a pattern that I see often and I personally use:

- create a skeleton file like `settings.json.sample` and put placeholder values for your keys
- copy that file to `settings.json` and put the real values
- add `settings.json` to `.gitignore`
- in the readme add instructions to rename `settings.json.sample` to `settings.json` and populate with actual values